Growth of Projective-hilbert and Hibert-injective ratios
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two finite dimensional Hilbert spaces.
The behaviour of $\rho(X,Y):=\sup_{z\in X\otimes Y\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|z\|_\pi}{\|z\|_\varepsilon}$, where $\pi$ denotes the projective tensor norm and $\varepsilon$ the injective tensor norm, is fairly well understood. We have
$$\rho=\text{min}(\text{dim}(X),\text{dim}(Y)).$$
My question is as follows: if we instead define $\rho^1_{\mathcal H}(X,Y):=\sup \frac{\|z\|_\pi}{\|z\|_{\text{Hilb}}}, \rho_{\mathcal H}^2:=\sup \frac{\|z\|_\text{Hilb}}{\|z\|_{\varepsilon}}$, where $\|z\|_{\text{Hilb}}$ is the Hilbert tensor norm, what can we say about them?
Of course, $\rho_{\mathcal H}\le \rho$, so we know that they cannot grow faster than linearly in the dimensions. However, I was unable to find any reference on their asymptotic growth (or some lower bounds): I assume $\rho^1$ and $\rho^2$ do grow linearly wrt $\text{min}(\text{dim}(X), \text{dim}(Y))$, but I find myself unable to prove it.
